# htaccess redirect according to IP

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, ip

Let's say my server looks like this:

```
/www/.htaccess
/www/index.php
/www/temp/index.php
```

And my personal IP (not the server's!) is 127.0.0.1*

(* ok, that's impossible, but for the sake of argument...)

I would like to redirect (301/302) everyone EXCEPT that IP to /temp/index.php

My current code looks like:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_HOST} !^127\.0\.0\.1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/temp/*$
RewriteRule \$ /temp/* [R=302,L]
```

However I get a 500 error.

Comment: If you get a 500 error, look in Apache's error log to see what the error actually is

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind, these htaccess file are hard to work with. I used some PHP code in my main index.php file instead.

Comment: @nicorellius Anything required an elevated IQ to understand and maintain is retarded. I've been using `.htaccess` files for the last 5 years or so. They're a pain in the ass and the weakest link in my job. They hardly ever get the job done effectively and anyone with enough intelligence knows s/he should be avoiding them at all costs.